# Css position corner absolute bottom left

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to add a supplementary corner to my design and one should go under the content box regardless the size of the content in that box.

As you can see there the corner fits ok for the 2nd box but not for the first.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cnmWh/

**HTML code here:**

```
<div class="title_container">
        <div class="hook_bottom_left"></div>
        <div class="title ">
        <p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
    </div>


<div class="title_container">
        <div class="hook_bottom_left"></div>
        <div class="title ">
        <p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
           </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS here:**

```
.title_container {position: relative; min-height: 112px; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 5px; display:block;}
.title { position: absolute; background:url("img/hash_light.png");  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8; padding: 15px; z-index: 10;  
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 16px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 16px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 16px);
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  overflow: hidden; }

.hook_bottom_left{position: absolute; left:0; bottom:17px; border-left: 8px solid #000; border-bottom:8px solid #000; width: 40px;height: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnmWh/2/)

I took away `min-height`, made the text `position:relative;` and made it `bottom:0`.

The `min-height` was going to not let the hook go to the bottom if it was smaller than `122px`, which is why it 'dangled' below it when on `bottom:0;`.

The text was `position:absolute` which meant that they weren't taking up any width (causing all sorts of overlapping errors). As soon as they were `position:relative`, the hook could get their correct height.

---

[JsFiddle with `:before` element](http://jsfiddle.net/cnmWh/3/)

This one takes away

```
<div class="hook_bottom_left"></div>
```

and instead inserts the 'hook' using `:before` on `.title_container`.

This means you no longer have to use a `div` for the hook, and `.title_container` classes will have it automatically.

Comment: ...and then do it with a `:before` pseudo-element instead of a `div`. :)